# Is it possible to compile a Go program with specific flags for coverage analysis?

Tags: testing, automation, go, code-coverage

Is it possible to compile a Go program with specific flags for coverage analysis?

The use case:

- Compile an app;
- Run functional automated tests;
- Analyse coverage;

Should be something similar to **Gcov** or **Python coverage**.

Many Thanks!

Comment: See http://blog.golang.org/cover .

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Go has the cover tool (as of version 1.2) incorporated into the test process. `go test` alone will compile your program and run any automated tests you may have. Adding the `-cover` flag will provide statistics on test coverage.

To run it:

```
go test -cover
```

You can also output a coverage profile:

```
go test -coverprofile=coverage.out
```

and then view it with:

```
go tool cover -func=coverage.out
```

or

```
go tool cover -html=coverage.out
```

for HTML formatted output (with colour coding).

See http://blog.golang.org/cover , `go tool cover -h` and `go help testflag` for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I read about go tool cover. Doesn't it run  only unit tests written in Go?
I have a bunch of functional automated tests written in Python and I'd like to measure how much code is covered by those tests.
Thanks

Comment: If you're looking to run the python test code against the go code (possibly client / server testing?) you could always call it from your Go test code using `os/exec` (http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/)